# How do you limit use of a web site to a particular company's active directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, active-directory, iis-7.5

I've developed a web application in asp.net/MVC/RAZOR/C#.  The client wants a user to go to this site and not have to enter a login/password if they are from a certain domain.  Users outside that domain can use a standard logins screen entering their login and password.  I've never worked with Active Directory before and my work with IIS is limited.  Can someone explain how to set this up?

From this link, http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication, I determined I need to use Windows Authentication option in IIS.  However, all this does is prompt the user for a username and password when they go to the site.  Right now Authentication is set so Windows Authentication enabled with response "HTTP 401 Challenge" and the enabled provider is "Negoiate: Kerberos".  How do I avoid this login screen and pass the user's Active Directory username, group, and domain down to the website?

If I get past the login screen, I try to get the user's identity using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.  However, this shows "IIS APPPOOL" no matter who I log in as.  How can I get the Active Directory username?  (and group)

I added the following code to my web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
     <authorization>
       <allow users="DOMAINNAME\*" />
       <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
      ...
```

Before I found the IIS link above I tried the code listed on these sites:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/458039/Application-Login-through-Active-Directory-LDAP
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5173/Web-based-Active-Directory-Login
These work to authenticate the user, but they require a password which I don't have.  I couldn't find a way to get the password, which led me to look further and find the info on IIS.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to set it up.

If anyone could give me some simple steps on how to set this up, I'd appreciate it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to limit a website, to be used only by users in a specific Active Directory group.

If you wanted to use the same method, you could just set the group name to "Domain Users" to allow all users. Like so:

```
var User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
var isUser = User.IsInRole(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SystemUsersADGroupname"));
```

I then added the following to web.config, to define the required group name:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SystemUsersADGroupname" value="mydomain\Domain Users" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I could then check on the value of the `isUser` variable, to determine if a user was allowed to continue or not.